# MathJS parse values from input field

Tags: javascript, html, input, mathjs

I'm trying to parse some values like `x^2` and `x` from an input field, then dividing them using mathjs

This is my JS

```js
function LDivide() {
            ldft = document.getElementById("LD1").value;
            ldst = document.getElementById("LD2").value;

            var LDans = math.simplify(math.parse(ldft / ldst));
            document.getElementById("LDansBox").innerHTML = LDans;
            document.getElementById("LDansBox").style.display = "inline"
        }
```

html as follows. I'd put `x^2` in the first field and `x` in the second, for example, in order to get `x` as an answer because `x^2/x = x`

```html
<input type="text" id="LD1" placeholder="First Term"> | <input type="text" id="LD2" placeholder="Second Term"><br>
<button id="LDSubmit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="LDivide()">=</button><br>
<p class="ansBox" id="LDansBox"></p>
```

It simply says `NaN`.

I've tried searching for a solution to no success.

Comment: paste HTML code too, looks like you have division by zero

Comment: @diavolic There ya go!

Comment: I just checked your code and everything works fine. Open console in browser (F12), may be there some errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

`math.parse` should get a string representing the math expression (or an array of strings representing expressions). You are providing the result of a division made with a javascript expression.

Try making a string with your expression.

```js
let expression = `${ldft} / ${ldst}`
let LDans = math.simplify(math.parse(expression))
```